# Jest – issue with export { default as

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have an `export { default as Scroll } from './scroll';` export in on of my `index.js` files.

Jest is throwing me an error saying:

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined

      15 | export { default as Scroll } from './scroll';
      16 | 
    > 17 | 
         | ^
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: I think you meant `import`

Comment: This syntax `export { default as Scroll } from './scroll';` is importing the `default` export from the `./scroll` and exporting it as a `Scroll`. This is the same as writting e.g. `import _Scroll from './scroll'; export const Scroll = _Scroll;`

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: @kraf I replaced it with a regular syntax (as stated in my comment above). The codebase had some not-well-structured imports (like file A importing from file B and vice-versa) – that might have been an issue.

Comment: Oh wow that was it actually, the import order was different in the tests, it was a cyclical import issue, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it will be helpful to anybody but well:

I had not-well-structured imports in the codebase that were creating circular imports and this was causing the issue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

I was using js files and my environment was expecting `commonJS` so either I had to use either `module.exports` or convert my files to `.ts` to use `import` and `export` properly.